# Trying to run a DELETE query using DAO in VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

Im using Access 2013 and Excel 2013. In terms of References, I am using Microsoft Office 15.0 Access database engine Object Library.

So I am trying to run a DELETE query in VBA. Here is what I have so far

```
Sub UpdatePartList()
    Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rsTable As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsQuery As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsSql As DAO.Recordset

    Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set dbs = ws.OpenDatabase("P:\Distribution Purchasing\Kit Bids\Kit Parts Query.accdb")

    'deletes previous part numbers
    Sql = "DELETE * FROM [Kit Parts]"
    Set rsSql = dbs.OpenRecordset(Sql, dbOpenDynaset)
```

When I run a SELECT query for the same table, it works just fine. But when I try to DELETE, I get this error.

> " Run-time error '3219': Invalid operation. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DAO`'s `OpenRecordSet` is not appropriate for `Delete` queries, which do not return any recordset object. Use the `Execute` method instead:

Change

> ```
> Set rsSql = dbs.OpenRecordset(Sql, dbOpenDynaset)
> ```

to

```
dbs.Execute(Sql)
```

also there's no need for `*` in the Delete SQL statement. Although Access will accept it, other systems probably won't.

Comment: thanks that worked! but now Im getting a "could not delete from specified table" error. I closed the database and no one else is using it right now

Comment: @J.Doe you might have integrity rules related to it. You cannot remove records that are used as foreign keys from other tables.

Comment: nevermind I figured it out. thank you all so much for helping me!

Comment: I upvoted the responses. Is accepting answer different?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your SQL as @Rahul suggested, plus change your last line of code to:

```
dbs.Execute sql
```